# i want to update the state before the component render the "else" in the "if else" statement

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, react-hooks, setstate

i am kinda reposting a question i posted earlier since i think that i didn't ask it well!

so i am using axios to make HTTP requests to a json-server api. all these requests are put inside a file i called "persons.js".

```
import axios from "axios";
const URL = "http://localhost:3001/persons";

const getPersons = () => {
  return axios.get(URL).then((res) => res.data);
};

const addPerson = (person) => axios.post(URL, person);
// this is where i have the probelm (i think)
const updatePerson = (person, number, setErrMsg) => {
  axios
    .put(`${URL}/${person[0].id}`, {
      name: person[0].name,
      number,
    })
//i wanted the change the state of the App.js from this line after there is an error
    .catch((err) => setErrMsg("err"));
};

const deletePerson = (person) => axios.delete(`${URL}/${person.id}`);

export { getPersons, addPerson, deletePerson, updatePerson };
```

and i have this feature where -everytime the user add or update a person's phone- there is a component called "PersonNotification" that render an `h1` element that say either "the phone was added" or "updated".
but  i want to have another "notification" that say "this phone doesn't exist anymore" if the phone -that the user wanted to update- gets deleted

here is the `PersonNotification` component

```
import React from "react";
import "./PersonNotification.css";

const PersonNotification = ({ notification, errMsg }) => {
  if (errMsg.length > 0) {
    return <h1 className="err">{notification}</h1>;
  }
  if (notification.length === 0) {
    return <></>;
  } else {
    return <h1 className="notification">{notification}</h1>;
  }
};

export default PersonNotification;
```

now; the way i'm doing this (rendering the error message that the user has been deleted) is with the promise error that appear in the console when the user try to update a non existing phone

so in the function `updatePerson` that is in the `persons.js` file

```
const updatePerson = (person, number, setErrMsg) => {
  axios
    .put(`${URL}/${person[0].id}`, {
      name: person[0].name,
      number,
    }).catch((err) => setErrMsg("err"));
};
```

there's the third argument that i called "setErrMsg", this sets the state `ErrMsg` that is in the App.js file, when there is an error (that the phone doesn't exist anymore)

but the problem i have the this "setErrMsg" gets exucuted late or something (i checked it with the react dev tool).

**here is (some of)the App.js code**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import {
  getPersons,
  addPerson,
  deletePerson,
  updatePerson,
} from "./services/persons";
import Filter from "./components/Filter";
import Form from "./components/Form";
import Phonebook from "./components/Phonebook";
import PersonNotification from "./components/PersonNotification";
const App = () => {
  const [persons, setPersons] = useState([]);
  const [newName, setNewName] = useState("");
  const [newNumber, setNewNumber] = useState("");
  const [query, setQuery] = useState("");
  const [searchValue, setSearchValue] = useState([]);
  const [notification, setNotification] = useState("");
  const [errMsg, setErrMsg] = useState("");

  // fetching the data from json-server (i,e: db.json)
  useEffect(() => {
    getPersons().then((res) => setPersons(res));
  }, []);
  // function that fires after the submit
  const personsAdder = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const personsObject = { name: newName, number: newNumber };

    //checking if the name exists
    const nameChecker = persons.filter(
      (person) => person.name === personsObject.name
    );
    console.log(errMsg);
    if (nameChecker.length > 0) {
      const X = window.confirm(
        `${personsObject.name} already exists do you want to update the number`
      );

      if (X === true) {
        // updating the number if the user confirmed
        updatePerson(nameChecker, newNumber, setErrMsg);
        const personsCopy = persons;
        const index = personsCopy.indexOf(nameChecker[0]);
        personsCopy[index] = {
          id: personsCopy[index].id,
          name: personsCopy[index].name,
          number: newNumber,
        };

        setPersons([...personsCopy]);
        setNewName("");
        setNewNumber("");
        //the function the shows the notification for 5 seconds after the content was updated
        const notificationSetter = () => {
          let X = "";
          if (errMsg.length > 0) {
            X = `you can't update${nameChecker[0].name} because it doesn't exist anymore`;
          } else {
            X = `${nameChecker[0].name} was updated`;
          }
          setNotification(X);

          setTimeout(() => {
            setNotification("");
            setErrMsg("");
          }, 5000);
        };
        notificationSetter();
      }
    } else {
      //adding a new user if the name was not already in the phonebook
      setPersons(persons.concat(personsObject));
      addPerson(personsObject);
      setNewName("");
      setNewNumber("");
      //the function the shows the notification for 5 seconds after the content was added
      const notificationSetter = () => {
        setNotification(`${personsObject.name} was added`);
        setTimeout(() => {
          setNotification("");
        }, 5000);
      };
      notificationSetter();
    }
  };
//...
```

***i want to know why is "setErrMsg" gets exucuted late!, and what is a better way to have the notification that says "the phone doesn't exist anymore"?***

Comment: What do you mean by "it gets executed late"? It's the error handler of an async call; it'll get executed when the async call fails, whenever that may be. You may just be missing some important asynchronous programming concepts.

Comment: @Dave Newton i mean that when i look in the React dev tool; i have the errMsg changing after the other state (it's delayed by a second or so)

Comment: And I'm saying that makes perfect sense: your other state changes will happen before any HTTP request has a chance to complete, so if the error happens after the Axios call is made, the rest of your code has already executed. That's why I'm saying I think you're not clear on the async nature of JS: the HTTP call is async, so success/error callbacks outside of your mainline code. Same with setting React state: state is not immediately updated.

Comment: @Dave Newton, so what can i do?, can please help me with something?

Comment: My advice would be to start "smaller": there's a large chunk of code and state here, and managing it all is making it more conceptually difficult than it needs to be. The fundamental issues will be the same, but easier to think about. I *think* you want to only run the code after the call to `updatePerson` after `updatePerson` completes *successfully* (but not sure; there might be other logic basic on success/failure). The code has to be arranged to support that, e.g., with an `await` and an error check (there are other options).